# how to do ngFor inside ngFor dynamically in angular 8?

Tags: arrays, angular, angular-material, ngfor

Hi what i trying to achieve is ngFor with dynamic value inside ngFor, is this possible? i try using ngModel inside it too and it didn't work out. Here is what i do :

inside my home.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

export interface Condition {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}

export interface ListProduk {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}

export interface DragBox {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}

export interface ListModel {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
  single_item: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  conditions: Condition[] = [
    { value: 'if', viewValue: 'IF' },
    { value: 'else', viewValue: 'ELSE' },
    { value: 'then', viewValue: 'THEN' },
    { value: 'if else', viewValue: 'IF ELSE' },
    { value: 'or', viewValue: 'OR' },
    { value: 'and', viewValue: 'AND' }
  ];

  listProduks: ListProduk[] = [
    { value: 'mcm-508', viewValue: 'MCM-508' },
    { value: 'bl-100 pl', viewValue: 'BL-100 PL' },
    { value: 'bl-150 bl', viewValue: 'BL-150 BR' },
    { value: 'bl-302gs', viewValue: 'BL-302GS' },
    { value: 'bl-52gl', viewValue: 'BL-52GL' }
  ];

  listModels: ListModel[] = [
    { value: 'conditions', viewValue: 'Condition', single_item:'condition' },
    { value: 'listProduks', viewValue: 'List Produk', single_item:'listProduk' },
  ]

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    moveItemInArray(this.listModels, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  }

}
```

and then here is my home.component.html :

```
<p>home works!</p>

<div cdkDropList cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal" class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let listModel of listModels" cdkDrag>
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Pick {{listModel.value}} :</mat-label>
            <mat-select>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let {{listModel.single_item}} of {{listModel.value}}" [value]="{{listModel.single_item}}.value">
                    test
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <div>
            <i class="material-icons">
                arrow_right_alt
            </i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i try to do loop the mat-select dynamically, since i want it loop an array that have different name, i need value in listModel array to print to *ngFor inside mat-select. Which is this line :

```
            <mat-option *ngFor="let {{listModel.single_item}} of {{listModel.value}}" [value]="{{listModel.single_item}}.value">
                test
            </mat-option>
```

how to do this properly?

UPDATED QUESTION After update my code with Ahmed comment, which is my Html is looked like this :

```
<p>home works!</p>

<div cdkDropList cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal" class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let listModel of listModels" cdkDrag>
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Pick {{listModel.value}} :</mat-label>
            <mat-select>
                <mat-option *ngFor="let a of listModel.value" [value]="a.value">
                    {{a.viewValue}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <div>
            <i class="material-icons">
                arrow_right_alt
            </i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this give me an error like this :

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'conditions' of
>   type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.

what did i missed?

Comment: i have answered something similar a while ago, that's the recursivity principle. Here is the link, in cas it might help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58061294/angular-nested-categories-and-ngfor-loop/58061496#58061496

Comment: you have an issue with the 2nd loop , you should use it without brackets .

    `<mat-option *ngFor="subitem of listModel.value" [value]="subitem.value">
      test
    </mat-option>`

Comment: @AhmedEl-sayed after i try it, i got an error like this : ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object 'conditions' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: @KeVin , that means your response array is not a valid JSON value , **check the value of "listModel.value"**

Comment: the value is conditions, nothing different when i replace listModel.value, with "conditions" string, it worked, but when printed with listModel.value, why it said its a string?

Comment: listModel.value contain value conditions, and it said it's a string so it give me error, but when i change listModel.value to conditions string, it will loop, what did i missed?

Comment: @KeVin , can you update me with an example for full array of data ? , i think listModel.value contains string value or not right array so it show error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200351/discussion-between-ahmed-el-sayed-and-ke-vin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display this using a function, which would return the correct array. We are calling this in the template. **BE CAREFUL**, I would never recommend calling a function in template, if it is just all possible. This can seriously hurt performance in an app. But if you don't have much content on this page, it is pretty safe to use. So I would suggest the following:

```
<div *ngFor="let value of getList(listModel.value)">
```

and the function would return the correct array:

```ts
getList(value) {
  return this[value]
}
```

---

You could also make a slight change to the model and pass an optional parameter with the array with the correct array to the object itself. You can do this in `OnInit`:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.listModels.forEach(x => {
    x.customArray = this[x.value]
  })
}
```

and use it like normal iteration in `*ngFor`:

```ts
<div *ngFor="let value of listModel.customArray">
```

**Here's a [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rnsbs5?file=src/app/app.component.ts) with both options**

Comment: thanks it's worked! i choose second way, to modified the model. and thanks for the stackblitz, it was big help. and i found about the model attribute which is written like customArray?: any[] 
There is "?" Question mark in it, what is the meaning of "?" there?

Comment: @KeVin good choice! :) `customArray?` means that it's an optional property, so if you were to type some object to `ListModel`, without that property, your compiler wouldn't complain that it's missing. Also I was lazy and used `any[]` there. You really should do something like... `customArray?: ListProduk[] | DragBox[] | Condition []` which means that `customArray` is either of these models.

Comment: Also I though see, that all of those models are the same, so in theory you could just have one model that covers all three instead of having 3 of the same just named differently. But that is just a detail :)